# Unable to delete an array element using php array_diff function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have added few values in Wordpress option table like below:

> option_name = optionLists
>
> option_values = Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4

I retrieved those values using PHP like below:

```
$option_lists = get_option('optionLists');
$myOption = explode("," , $option_lists );
```

So, here `$myOption` is an array and if I print `$myOption` using `print_r($myOption)`, it will show result like below:

> Array ( [0] => Option1 [1] => Option2 [2] => Option3 [3] => Option4 )

Now, I want to delete one array element from the above array, say it is `Option3`. I wrote that like below:

```
$remvOption = array('4' => 'Option3');
$new_option = array_diff($myOption, $remvOption);
```

The expected output should be like below:

> Array ( [0] => Option1 [1] => Option2 [3] => Option4 )

But, it is still showing:

> Array ( [0] => Option1 [1] => Option2 [2] => Option3 [3] => Option4 )

May I know where I am doing the mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WNGPE7

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

But no need to have the ID of the item - just put the value itself

```
$myOption = array('Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3', 'Option4');
$remvOption = array('Option3');
$new_option = array_diff($myOption, $remvOption);
```

And then make sure you are printing the correct variable:

```
print_r($new_option);
```

This code gives me output:

```
 Array ( [0] => Option1 [1] => Option2 [3] => Option4 )
```

Comment: `array_diff()` doesn't care about keys, so this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @billyonecan - yes, you are correct, but it wont hurt to remove it either.

Comment: In $myOption variable the options are coming dynamically. I don't know how many options I have. So, I can't put value manually in array. I just made a string (Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4) value an array using explode function. I am just unable to do it when I am creating array using explode function. Manually it is possible and I know that. Thanks for your help but it is not the answer.

Comment: I only put that there as a demo to show the code works. You dont need to load 'myOption' first - you can do it in your example. My point is your code works as you have posted it. But you havent shown how you are printing the 'new option' - so my guess is you are doing it wrong somehow.

Comment: The mistake was in this code: `$myOption = explode(",", $option_lists );` there will be a space after ',' inside the double quotation.